# AWS EC2 security to only allow HTTP requests originating as a result of browser accessing static s3 content

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

As part of distributed deployment on AWS, we have moved all static web assets, including angularjs files and dependencies to an AWS S3 bucket (static website). Angularjs controllers have complete API URL pointing to a nodejs server running on an EC2 instance. I am trying to figure out what is a good way to **prevent Nodejs server from processing any HTTP requests other than the ones originating from angularjs controller.**

Option -1 ) I cannot use S3 IP address for obvious reasons as incoming IP address for EC2 security group hosting the Nodejs server.

Option -2) I can use VPC Endpoint, but its more of a solution to allow EC2 in private subnet to access an S3 bucket.

Option -3) I can have another EC2 instance hosting a reverse proxy which the S3 angularjs will connect to. This reverse proxy will forward the request to EC2 instance running nodejs.

Option -4) Use AWS Nat Gateway, do not think its much different from option # 3.

Need folks to chime in with their thoughts keeping in mind security.

Comment: Who cares if the requests come from somewhere other than your app?  You can't prevent people from doing this, and nor should it matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of AngularJS, it's all JavaScript. Your code is run from the use's web browser, not S3 bucket.

You can implement this by validating the Origin HTTP header. But that can be easily hacked.

The best possible solution is provide a service which generates some kind of session token, add it as part of all requests in some header field in AngularJS while sending requests to your NodeJS server and validate it for every request.

Comment: Yep, and that session token can be easily worked around as well.  There's no sure-fire way to do what's being asked.

Comment: I agree, the question did mislead the fact that the request is coming from S3, when it's actually the browser (I will rectify the mistake). As for token, that seems to be an inexpensive approach given the fact that we are using JavaScript across the board.  What I was trying to achieve is come up with a solution to prevent DOS style attack on EC2 server

Comment: Providing this context completely changes the question. Please have a look at this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/340307/how-can-i-prevent-a-ddos-attack-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: I agree with your comment and the provided link. Appreciate your response, this thread can be closed for now.